# Change active section of form according to different condition

Tags: php, html

I have a form where users can register in my site. I distinguish the new users and already registered users from their email. Thus, if an already registered user submits the registration form I would like to direct him to the FORGET PASSWORD page. if a new user submits I would like to direct to the WELCOME TO SITE page.
But, I do not know how to handle the active section of form since the active section just get an URL and users always direct to the given URL.
What can I do about the active section of form? Can I give two URLs and a condition for choosing one of them to the active section?

Best Regards,
Vahid

Comment: Just make that decision in the script your form data is send to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP pseudo-code:

```
    <?php 
        if(user exists){ $url = "forgetpassword.html"; } 
        else { $url = "welcome.html";}

       ?>
```

HTML pseudo-code:

```
    <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the email address in your database.

If found: echo header("Location: url for your forgot password page");

else

echo header("Location: url for your login page");

See: [Redirect to specified URL on PHP script completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353803/redirect-to-specified-url-on-php-script-completion)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a redirection like this: `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`

form

```
<form method="POST" action="register.php">
    ...
</form>
```

register.php

```
    $result = checkRegistration($email,...,...);

    if($result) {
        header("Location: welcome.php");
    } else {
        header("Location: password.php");
    }
```