# codeigniter or PHP - how to go to a URL after a specific AJAX POST submission

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, redirect

I am successfully inserting data into my database in codeigniter via a an ajax post from javascript:

```
//JAVASCRIPT:

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: submissionURL,
   data: submissionString,
   failure: function(errMsg) {
        console.error("error:",errMsg);
   },
   success: function(data){
        $('body').append(data); //MH - want to avoid this
   }
});

//PHP:
public function respond(){
    $this->load->model('scenarios_model');
    $responseID = $this->scenarios_model->insert_response();
    //redirect('/pages/view/name/$responseID') //MH - not working, so I have to do this
    $redirectURL = base_url() . 'pages/view/name/' . $responseID;
    echo "<script>window.location = '$redirectURL'</script>";
}
```

But the problem is that I can't get codeigniter's redirect function to work, nor can I get PHP's header location method to work, as mentioned here:

[Redirect to specified URL on PHP script completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353803/redirect-to-specified-url-on-php-script-completion)

either - I'm guessing this is because the headers are already sent? So as you can see, in order to get this to work, I have to echo out a script tag and dynamically insert it into the DOM, which seems janky. How do I do this properly?

Comment: try echo $redirectURL.. And in the $.ajax, success: function(data) { window.location=data }

Comment: header location won't have impact on page where  ajax is called from anyway. Why not do a conventional post without ajax?

Comment: It seems like you have not loaded codeignter url helper. Most likely your script is throwing en error. Check you console log for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can 'return' the url in respond function and use it in js

 PHP :

```
public function respond(){
    // code
    $redirectURL = base_url() . 'pages/view/name/' . $responseID;
    return json_encode(['url' => $redirectURL]);
}
```

JS :

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: submissionURL,
   data: submissionString,
   dataType: 'JSON',
   failure: function(errMsg) {
        console.error("error:",errMsg);
   },
   success: function(data){
      window.location = data.url
   }
});
```

Comment: This is better, thanks. Still would like to know how to do this just with PHP. If anyone stumbles on this and has an idea, feel free to respond and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

you have to concatenate the variable. That's all.

```
 redirect('controller_name/function_name/parameter/'.$redirectURL);
```

Comment: yeah - I did this, but the redirect doesn't work - I think it's a headers issue maybe. If I put into the javascript a "success" function and echo out the response from PHP, I get all the data from the proper view, but it gets appended to the current view - the browser does not redirect.